# Have printed bibliography include all entries cited from several .tex files

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I am using biblatex with the biber backend (and compiling with XeLaTeX, if it happens to be important).

The default behavior of `\printbibliography` is to only add to the references manually cited in a given .tex file. I am aware you can add entries that are not in the document with `\nocite{*}`, or `\nocite{key}`, but what if there are two separate .tex files compiled entirely separately that should have the same bibliography? How can I have the `\printbibliography` command add the cited resources from both .tex files, but nothing else? For example...

**sources.bib**

```
@book{abook,
    author = a,
    title = a,
}
@book{another,
    author = b,
    title = b,
}
@book{athird,
    author = c,
    title = c,
}
```

**a.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresources{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
Source 1 \autocite{abook}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**b.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresources{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
Source 1 \autocite{another}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would like the biliographies of both these pdfs to have book a and book b but not book c. I would concede that I would have to recompile both of them whenever one is updated to keep the bibliographies in sync; this would be okay.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you.... but why don't you keep two separate bibliography files? It seems that you are complicating yourself unnecessarily...

Comment: @scd For example, say I have to make a presentation with two different mediums: a slideshow and a report. I keep these as separate .tex files because one is being compiled with beamer at say 16:9 resolution and the other with plain LaTeX at A4. I want the full bibliography in the report, as I don't think anyone wants to read a bibliography from a slideshow, but sensibly I still want it to include anything referenced in the slideshow.